# Android dlopen failed: file offset for the library "libnexplayerengine.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hello guys I need your help. I'm stuck with this problem for almost 3 days and cannot go forward.

I'm trying to integrate NexPlayer into my app, but I'm getting this error msg:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset for the library "/data/app/com.abscbn.iwanttv-1/lib/arm/libnexplayerengine.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0
```

I have already put all .so files to libs folder

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Any idea how to debug and fix this problem? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow all the steps listed here under "How to create an x86 player app"? Like copying all the files to all the different places? It mentions more than just the libs folder... https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/application-development-using-nexstreaming-nexplayer-sdk

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I did already

Comment: And you did this where is says "The libraries from app/libs/x86 need to be loaded in InitManager() in Java* source code for the application "

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. I'd like to know what >= file size: 0 >= 0 means

Comment: Can you add the Java code for how you are loading the library?

Comment: The error is saying the file offset for the file is greater than or equal to 0. The first 0 in `0 >= 0` is the file offset. Not sure what that means exactly, though

Comment: The file size is zero. It isn't built correctly.

Comment: @EJP how do I address this?