# how i can implement live streaming in android

Tags: android, youtube-api, live-streaming

I want to create a live stream functionality in my android app. I got an example from this link:

https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme.

While running this code i got an error, "`libffmpeg`" can't load. To solve this issue i downloaded pre-built '`libffmpeg`' and added to my project. After that I getting the issue:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset 
for the library "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.watchme-2/
lib/arm/libffmpeg.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0.
```

How I can solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Sven, Thanks for your response. While I am running yt-watchme sample project I am getting the above issue. In that project I added 'libffmpeg.so' under lib directory and build gradle I added these code: sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started)? The YouTube Live Streaming API lets you create, update, and manage live events on YouTube. Using the API, you can schedule events (broadcasts) and associate them with video streams, which represent the actual broadcast content.

For your error: `dlopen failed: file offset for the library`, you may check on this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508670/5832311). Make sure that you have downloaded and copied the files properly.

You can also check on this [Java Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/java) that used the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) which are available for the YouTube Live Streaming API.