# Error after including a 2nd JNI library to my Android project (OpenCV)

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, libraries

I'm trying to add OpenCV to an existing Android project of mine but while merging them I ran into the following error:

```
12-08 16:15:21.951 22052-22052/ai.inbi.face_recognition_robot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: ai.inbi.wonderful_face_recognition_robot, PID: 22052
                                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load uvcNative from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ai.inbi.wonderful_face_recognition_robot-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ai.inbi.wonderful_face_recognition_robot-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                                                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
```

I tried to manually comment out all references to OpenCV but unless I delete all OpenCV files from my libs folder the existing library (com.qihancloud.opensdk) fails to find it's own library functions.
The folder structure of my libraries is like this:
[image: project folder structure]

If I remove the OpenCV library files before compiling everything works well.
Also my standalone OpenCV project is working but as soon as I try to combine them it fails to execute.

My app build.gradle file can be seen here:
https://pastebin.com/Z7hPH3vy

And my CMakeLists.txt
https://pastebin.com/gGwgWtxP

Comment: You must also share the CMakeLists.txt file, which is responsible for the native build

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the file **libuvcNative.so** has not been installed with your APK. This can happen for a wild variety of root causes.

Your case is exactly same as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152287/192373). The **QihanOpenSDK_1.1.8.0.aar** only has an **armeabi** version of **libuvcNative.so**. The fix is to change line #15 of [build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/Z7hPH3vy) to read

```
 abiFilters 'armeabi'
```

But I must confess that your [CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/gGwgWtxP) puzzled me. For me,

```
set_target_properties(lib_qihan PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} /libs/QihanOpenSDK_1.1.8.0.aar)
```

does not work. To be sincere,

```
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} /libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
```

also does not match my books. For the latter, I believe that you simply added a space while copy/pasting the script.

For the former, I know a special [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713565/192373) to have an **so** file from an imported **aar** used in native build.

I believe that your *working* version not only discards all OpenCV libraries, but also does not build the **libnative-lib.so**. This way, **cmake** does never look for **libuvcNative.so**, but still this native lib is deployed with the APK because the **aar** is a *compiled* dependency of your app. I guess that some of the **QihanOpenSDK** classes explicitly calls

```
System.loadLibrary("uvcNative")
```

If your **libnative-lib.so** does not use external symbols from **libuvcNative.so**, you don't need the trick I mentioned above and don't need to mention the **QihanOpenSDK** at all in your **CMakeLists.txt**.

Comment: Yes you were right! The OpenCV libraries got compiled though. Anyway, setting to armeabi was the solution! In addition to that I had to delete all other platform folders, for some reason it still went looking in there and crashed but once I removed them it finally worked as intendend. Thanks!